# How to convert System.DateTime? to System.DateOnly?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-6.0, dateonly

How can I convert nullable `DateTime` to nullable `DateOnly`?
So `DateTime?` to `DateOnly?`

The error says:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateOnly?' to
> 'System.DateTime?'

I can convert from `DateTime` to `DateOnly` by doing:

```
DateOnly mydate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(mydatetime);
```

but what about nullables?

I have a way but I don't think is the best idea...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static DateOnly? ToNullableDateOnly(this DateTime? input) 
{
    if (input == null) return null;
    return DateOnly.FromDateTime(input.Value);
}
```

Comment: I think something like this in my answer. There is no other way? No function inside the framework to do this?

Comment: It's similar, but extends yours to work as an extension (so it looks like it's part of the type),  and with less code and fewer operations (the `??` expands into something much larger that isn't needed).

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see the change. Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 11):

Let's make an method that does exactly the same as `FromDateTime`, just invoked as an extension on `DateTime`:

```
public static DateOnly ToDateOnly(this DateTime datetime) 
    => DateOnly.FromDateTime(datetime);
```

Now you can use the null-conditional member access operator `?.` to lift this method to its nullable version:

```
var myNullableDateOnly = myNullableDateTime?.ToDateOnly();
```

Unfortunately, C# has no "null-conditional static method call operator". Thus, we need this "extension method workaround".

Answer (score 2):

You can create a DateTime extension methods:

```
public static class DateTimeExtends
{
    public static DateOnly ToDateOnly(this DateTime date)
    {
        return new DateOnly(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
    }

    public static DateOnly? ToDateOnly(this DateTime? date)
    {
        return date != null ? (DateOnly?)date.Value.ToDateOnly() : null;
    }
}
```

And use on any DateTime instance:

```
DateOnly date = DateTime.Now.ToDateOnly();
```

NOTE: Not tested, maybe have a tipo error...

Comment: I like the approach in one line. ToDateOnly is already covered

Comment: The first method is losing the TimeZone info, and the second does unnecessary casting. Downvoted.

Comment: @funatparties It's has been written from my smartphone (NOTE: Not tested...). I can't do any better. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I just create this method, if someone has another one better I'll glad to accept it as answer

```
    public DateOnly? NullableDateTime_To_NullableDateOnly(DateTime? input) {
        if (input != null)
        {
            return DateOnly.FromDateTime(input ?? DateTime.Now); //this is irrelevant but...
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: dateOnly = dateTime.HasValue ? DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime.Value) : null;